# Why are deque's pop_front() and pop_back() not noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, deque, std, noexcept

Is there any reason that `std::deque`'s `pop_front()` and `pop_back()` are not `noexcept` in C++11 and higher or was that just forgotten?

Comment: How could they be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the standard doesn't specify `noexcept` on functions with a narrow contract (with a precondition which violation leads to UB). [N3279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf) and more recently [P0884](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0884r0.pdf) are talking about this and about how to decide whether a function should be `noexcept` or not (or conditionally).

This is the case for `std::deque`'s `pop_front` and `pop_back` but also on `front` and `back` where there is no call to a destructor. Same for `std::vector`'s `pop_back`, `front` and `back` for example.

Comment: This is correct. The idea was to allow implementations to throw an exception if they detected a contract violation. If these functions were marked as noexcept the program would call std::terminate.